# Public constructor of a private class

Tags: java, constructor

I am new to Java. I want to know what it is the use of *public* constructor in a *private* class. Private class inside the class can be initialized from the same class then what it is the use to make the constructor of private class to public?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        public AcceptThread() {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's any good reason to make that constructor `public`. Making the constructor `private` would have the same effect and make your intention much more clear.

Comment: This answer might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23161623/436524

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There doesn't seems to be any real use case for public or protected modifiers with private classes. If you have multiple classes in a single file though (but not nested or local), you need non-private constructors to instantiate the private classes.

```
// X.java

public class X {
    private Y y = new Y();
}

class Y {
    Y () {
        // if this were private, X wouldn't be able to create an instance of Y
    }
}
```

Actually *default* or `protected` visibility would be enough to create an instance in this case. All non-private modifiers allow you to create instances from other classes within the same package but practically have the same visibility.

- The private class isn't visible to classes outside of the package, so `public` methods have no use here.
- The private class can't be extended by classes outside of the package, so `protected` has no use either.
- Even when using reflections, a public constructor is not accessible by default from other packages and will throw a `IllegalAccessException`. It checks the class visibility first, then the member visibility.

The *default* modifier is the most restrictive modifier that allows you to directly call the constructor from other classes, so package-private seems to be the most appropriate visibility for the constructor and also any other non-private methods. This also has the advantage that if you change the class visibility in the future, you don't accidentally expose the constructor or any methods to the public.

Comment: It would be clearer/cleaner to make `Y()` package private.

Answer (score 8):

You know, I ask myself this question almost each time I make a private inner class, but I always assumed that there could be some (possibly contrived) reason for a public constructor.  So @kapep 's answer got me tingling and encouraged to find ways to require a public constructor on a private inner class, but the more I think and experiment with it, the more I think the holes are plugged.

Possible angles, all of which failed me:

- <strike>**Serialisation**</strike>:  When unmarshalling an object whose superclass is not serializable, the superclass needs a no-arg constructor *accessible from the subclass*.  So, `protected` should always suffice here.
- <strike>**Reflective tools**</strike>:  Code that uses reflection to get the inner class constructor through a returned instance.  Fails because the type visibility is checked first, as @kapep pointed out, though it leaves a rather interesting error message:

  > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class A can not access a member of class contrived.B$C with modifiers "public"
- <strike>**Inner class extension shenanigans**</strike>: Don't try this at home:

  ```
  package a;
  class Outer {
    private class Inner {
    }
  }

  package b;
  // compile error: Outer.Inner has private access in Outer
  class Extender extends a.Outer.Inner {
    Extender(a.Outer outer) {
      outer.super();
    }
  }
  ```

  Seemed promising at first, but I didn't get too far with that one.

---

In the end, I could not find a way to make a public constructor on a private inner class *useful*.

Then why is this technically legal despite having no use?  Probably because the compiler automagically inserts a no-arg public constructor when no other constructor is provided.  Hence the language should not disallow this constructs.  More of an artefact than a reason, though.