# Spring @Secured produces BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException while booting a web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Controller called **RequisitionController** that I annotate it with @Controller **("this is an implementation not an interface")**

I have another controller call **DashboardController**, this controller **@Autowire** RequisitionController in itself.

Now when I annotate any of the **@RequestMapping** methods of RequisitionController class with **@Secured** my project does not start.

**Here are something that I need to share:**

1. My project works without any problem if I don't annotate with @Secured
2. I used the method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14509142/1970299) and created interface, my app started but none of my request mapping worked and I got 404

Here is the full stack trace:

```
17813 [WARN] AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dashboardController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'requisitionController'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'requisitionController' is expected to be of type 'x.y.z.RequisitionController' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125'
17824 [ERROR] ContextLoader: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dashboardController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'requisitionController'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'requisitionController' is expected to be of type 'x.y.z.RequisitionController' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4600) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5066) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:742) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:718) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1736) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.7]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.7]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:361) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'requisitionController' is expected to be of type 'x.y.z.RequisitionController' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 60 more
30-Dec-2018 12:59:46.962 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
30-Dec-2018 12:59:46.963 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53775067/adding-micrometer-dependency-causes-weird-spring-proxy-issue/53775179#53775179

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved my problem with putting this on my configuration class

> @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)

and Adding this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But I just wanna know why my code broke !